# (Python) XGBoost: Early stopping with cross validation?

Tags: cross-validation, xgboost

Does the XGBoost package in Python allow for early stopping when using its cross validation function?

I read that the R package does this, but when I include `early_stopping_rounds=10` in my `xbg.cv()` it gives me the error:

```
TypeError: 'set' object does not support indexing
```

Answer (score 2):

I was having same problem. I changed `metrics={'xxx'}` to `metrics=['xxx']` and it worked.
Strange behavior, because before I put the `early_stopping_rounds`, `metrics={'xxx'}` was working.

Comment: Thank you this was helpful!